# #value! error for sum of offset range values

Tags: vba, excel, offset

Can anyone tell me why I'm getting #VALUE! error from using this function I made?
It seems pretty simple, but I'm new to VBA so I don't understand what's wrong, especially when I'm not receiving any errors from the compiler.

I'm trying to choose a year in the A column, and have the function's value be the sum of the diagonal 4 cells starting to the right of it.

```
 Function QTRtoANN(yearq As Range, age As Integer) As Double

    Dim qtr1 As Double
    Dim qtr2 As Double
    Dim qtr3 As Double
    Dim qtr4 As Double
    Dim qtr1OS As Double
    Dim qtr2OS As Double
    Dim qtr3OS As Double
    Dim qtr4OS As Double

    qtr1OS = (age / 12) + 3 * ((age / 12) - 1)
    qtr2OS = (age / 6) + 2 * ((age / 12) - 1)
    qtr3OS = (age / 4) + ((age / 12) - 1)
    qtr4OS = (age / 3)

    qtr1 = Range(yearq).Offset(qtr1OS, 0).Value
    qtr2 = Range(yearq).Offset(qtr2OS, -1).Value
    qtr3 = Range(yearq).Offset(qtr3OS, -2).Value
    qtr4 = Range(yearq).Offset(qtr4OS, -3).Value


    QTRtoANN = qtr1 + qtr2 + qtr3 + qtr4

End Function
```

Comment: You can't use `Range(yearq).Offset...` because `yearq` is already a range object, just reference it directly like `yearq.Offset...`

Comment: @tigeravatar Just changed it, but still have the error

Comment: You are also dividing `age` by 12, 6, 4, and 3, all of which can easily cause their respecitive offset values to not be whole numbers.  If `qtr10S` is something like `2.833333` for example, I'd expect an error, so make sure your calculations will result in whole numbers, or force it using `Round` or `Int`

Comment: Also, if `yearq` is column A - your column offset should be positive: 1, not -1. Positive = offset to the right.

Comment: I am only inputting ages that are multiples of 12, so it should only get whole numbers.  @tigeravatar

Comment: @BigBen That may be the issue, let me try changing that

Comment: Also why `Range(yearq)`? `yearq` is already a range

Comment: @SiddharthRout yea I edited that, i thought it was necesary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is your use of negative arguments (-1, -2, -3) as the *ColumnOffset* when offsetting from `yearq`. From a quick read of [MSDN - `Range.Offset` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-offset-property-excel), "positive values are offset to the right, and negative values are offset to the left." As is, the code is attempting to refer to columns to the left of Column A, causing your error.

Also as noted in the comments:

- `yearq` is already a `Range`, so just `yearq.Offset...`
- If `age` is not a multiple of 12, your division `age/12`, `age/6`, etc. will not result in a whole number, and the subsequent attempt to `Offset` will throw an error. *I did not make that change*, but you could `Round` or declare your variables `qtr1OS`, `qtr2OS`, etc.,  as `Int` to silently discard any decimal value.

So your revised `Function` could look something like this:

```
Function QTRtoANN(yearq As Range, age As Integer) As Double

    Dim qtr1 As Double
    Dim qtr2 As Double
    Dim qtr3 As Double
    Dim qtr4 As Double
    Dim qtr1OS As Double
    Dim qtr2OS As Double
    Dim qtr3OS As Double
    Dim qtr4OS As Double

    qtr1OS = (age / 12) + 3 * ((age / 12) - 1)
    qtr2OS = (age / 6) + 2 * ((age / 12) - 1)
    qtr3OS = (age / 4) + ((age / 12) - 1)
    qtr4OS = (age / 3)

    qtr1 = yearq.Offset(qtr1OS, 0).Value
    qtr2 = yearq.Offset(qtr2OS, 1).Value
    qtr3 = yearq.Offset(qtr3OS, 2).Value
    qtr4 = yearq.Offset(qtr4OS, 3).Value

    QTRtoANN = qtr1 + qtr2 + qtr3 + qtr4

End Function
```